# Update TextViews with mediaplayer paused and started (Combined with seekbar)

Tags: android, multithreading, seekbar

I have managed to change text on dragging or touching seekbar. The problem is to update the textviews when pause and play buttons are clicked.

This is what i have achieved so far and it updates the textviews accordingly

private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {

```
    if(mediaPlayer !=null){
        seekBarProgress.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100)); // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"
        totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        statusDuration = totalDuration - currentDuration;
    }

    if(currentDuration > 1000){

        btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //mMaterialProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Displaying Total Duration time
        TotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(statusDuration));
        // Displaying time completed playing
        CurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
    }


    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer !=null) {
        notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }

        };

        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
    }
}
```

Problem is here. On click events of two buttons placed inside a framelayout

```
btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isAvailable()) {
                // check if we are streaming
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();

                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_b);
                    btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    seekBarProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Paused but won't update text views");

                    // }
                } else {
                    // Resume song
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_b);
                        btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        seekBarProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        handler.removeCallbacks(notification);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Check here for playback please");
                        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                showMessage("Please enable internet and data to listen music");
            }


        }
    });
```

I had removed a callback for my runnable and start a new thread. New thread won't update the textviews like i have achieved previously

Comment: why you are not using runonuithread where you want to update text ?

Comment: same thing, primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() is running on a thread @Saveen

Comment: okay thats good but when you trying to update UI i.e text change then how it work ? You need to use runonuithread for updation.

Comment: are you sure you are getting currentDuration  in milliseconds ?

Comment: I feel stupid..i had to clean and build the project...its working now! @saveen thanks for your tip

Comment: don't worry, sometime it happened